# JScrollPane scrollbar doesnt work after GridBagLayout

Tags: java, mysql, database, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I am making an auto chat client like Cleverbot for school. I have 2 problems... 1) the scroll bar doesn't seem to work for some reason. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.lang.Math;

public class ChatBot extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    //Main method
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ChatBot();
    }
    //Swing settings
    JPanel window=new JPanel(){
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Image background = new ImageIcon("textEffect.png").getImage();
            int x = (window.getWidth() - background.getWidth(null)) / 2;
            int y = (window.getHeight() - background.getHeight(null)) / 2;
            g.drawImage(background,x,y,null,this);
        }
    };
    JLabel label=new JLabel("Say: ");
    JTextArea dialog=new JTextArea();
    JTextField input=new JTextField(46);
    JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(
        dialog,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
    );
    //Makes window and starts bot
    public ChatBot(){
        super("Pollockoraptor");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setEditable(false);
        dialog.setLineWrap(true);
        dialog.setOpaque(false);
        scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        input.addKeyListener(this);
        window.add(scroll);
        window.add(label);
        window.add(input);
        //background color; new Color(97, 118, 131) is a nice color
        window.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        add(window);
        setVisible(true);
        //Gui Layout
        window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        //Dialog
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        window.add(dialog, c);
        //Input box
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 10);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        window.add(input, c);
        //Label
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        window.add(label, c);
        input.requestFocus();
    }
    //knowledgeBase
    String[][] knowledgeBase={
        {"hi","hello","howdy","hey"},
        {"hi","hello","hey"},
        {"how are you", "how r u", "how r you", "how are u"},
        {"good","doing well"},
        {"shut up","noob","stop talking"}
    };
    //What to do when enter is pressed
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            input.setEditable(false);
            //get the user input
            String quote=input.getText();
            input.setText("");
            if(!quote.equals("")){
                addText("You:\t"+quote);
                quote.trim();
                while(quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='!' || quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='.' || quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='?'){
                    quote=quote.substring(0,quote.length()-1);
                }
                quote.trim();
                byte response=0;
                int j=0;
                //check the knowledgeBase for a match or change topic
                while(response==0){
                    //if a match is found, reply with the answer
                    if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),knowledgeBase[j*2])){
                        response=2;
                        int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*knowledgeBase[(j*2)+1].length);
                        addText("\nPollockoraptor:\t"+knowledgeBase[(j*2)+1][r]);
                    }
                    j++;
                    //if a match is not found, go to change topic
                    if(j*2==knowledgeBase.length-1 && response==0){
                        response=1;
                    }
                }
                //change topic if bot is lost
                if(response==1){
                    int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*knowledgeBase[knowledgeBase.length-1].length);
                    addText("\nPollockoraptor:\t"+knowledgeBase[knowledgeBase.length-1][r]);
                }
                addText("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    //other events
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            input.setEditable(true);
        }
    }
    //format the input
    public void addText(String str){
        dialog.setText(dialog.getText()+str);
    }
    //check the knowledgeBase for a match
    public boolean inArray(String in,String[] str){
        boolean match=false;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            if(str[i].equals(in)){
                match=true;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

I have everything else working, but I also need a way to make a database of responses that i can edit easily. How would I do this? Do I have to use MySQL or something like that? Is there a easier way I can do this where I can make a matrix similar to the one I have by reading a text file?

***************EDIT****************

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.lang.Math;

public class ChatBot extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    //Main method
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ChatBot();
    }
    //Swing settings
    JPanel window=new JPanel(){
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Image background = new ImageIcon("textEffect.png").getImage();
            int x = (window.getWidth() - background.getWidth(null)) / 2;
            int y = (window.getHeight() - background.getHeight(null)) / 2;
            g.drawImage(background,x,y,null,this);
        }
    };
    JLabel label=new JLabel("Say: ");
    JTextArea dialog=new JTextArea(5,30);
    JTextField input=new JTextField(46);
    JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(
        dialog,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
    );
    //Makes window and starts bot
    public ChatBot(){
        super("Pollockoraptor");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setEditable(false);
        dialog.setLineWrap(true);
        dialog.setOpaque(false);
        scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        input.addKeyListener(this);
        window.add(scroll);
        //background color; new Color(97, 118, 131) is a nice color
        window.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        add(window);
        setVisible(true);
        //Gui Layout
        window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        //Dialog
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        window.add(scroll, c);
        //Input box
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 10);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        window.add(input, c);
        //Label
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        window.add(label, c);
        input.requestFocus();
    }
    //knowledgeBase
    String[][] knowledgeBase={
        {"hi","hello","howdy","hey"},
        {"hi","hello","hey"},
        {"how are you", "how r u", "how r you", "how are u"},
        {"good","doing well"},
        {"shut up","noob","stop talking"}
    };
    //What to do when enter is pressed
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            input.setEditable(false);
            //get the user input
            String quote=input.getText();
            input.setText("");
            if(!quote.equals("")){
                addText("You:\t"+quote);
                quote.trim();
                while(quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='!' || quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='.' || quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='?'){
                    quote=quote.substring(0,quote.length()-1);
                }
                quote.trim();
                byte response=0;
                int j=0;
                //check the knowledgeBase for a match or change topic
                while(response==0){
                    //if a match is found, reply with the answer
                    if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),knowledgeBase[j*2])){
                        response=2;
                        int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*knowledgeBase[(j*2)+1].length);
                        addText("\nPollockoraptor:\t"+knowledgeBase[(j*2)+1][r]);
                    }
                    j++;
                    //if a match is not found, go to change topic
                    if(j*2==knowledgeBase.length-1 && response==0){
                        response=1;
                    }
                }
                //change topic if bot is lost
                if(response==1){
                    int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*knowledgeBase[knowledgeBase.length-1].length);
                    addText("\nPollockoraptor:\t"+knowledgeBase[knowledgeBase.length-1][r]);
                }
                addText("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    //other events
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            input.setEditable(true);
        }
    }
    //format the input
    public void addText(String str){
        dialog.append(str);
    }
    //check the knowledgeBase for a match
    public boolean inArray(String in,String[] str){
        boolean match=false;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            if(str[i].equals(in)){
                match=true;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

***************EDIT2****************

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.lang.Math;

public class ChatBot extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //Main method
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ChatBot();
    }
    //Swing settings
    JPanel window=new JPanel(){
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Image background = new ImageIcon("textEffect.png").getImage();
            int x = (window.getWidth() - background.getWidth(null)) / 2;
            int y = (window.getHeight() - background.getHeight(null)) / 2;
            g.drawImage(background,x,y,null,this);
        }
    };
    JLabel label=new JLabel("Say: ");
    JTextArea dialog=new JTextArea(5,30);
    JTextField input=new JTextField(46);
    JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(
        dialog,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
    );
    //Makes window and starts bot
    public ChatBot(){
        super("Pollockoraptor");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setEditable(false);
        dialog.setLineWrap(true);
        dialog.setOpaque(false);
        scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        input.addActionListener(this);
        window.add(scroll);
        //background color; new Color(97, 118, 131) is a nice color
        window.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        add(window);
        setVisible(true);
        //Gui Layout
        window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        //Dialog
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        window.add(scroll, c);
        //Input box
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 10);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        window.add(input, c);
        //Label
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        window.add(label, c);
        input.requestFocus();
    }
    //knowledgeBase
    String[][] knowledgeBase={
        {"hi","hello","howdy","hey"},
        {"hi","hello","hey"},
        {"how are you", "how r u", "how r you", "how are u"},
        {"good","doing well"},
        {"shut up","noob","stop talking"}
    };
    //What to do when enter is pressed
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //get the user input
        String quote=input.getText();
        input.setText("");
        if(!quote.equals("")){
            addText("You:\t"+quote);
            quote.trim();
            while(quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='!' || quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='.' || quote.charAt(quote.length()-1)=='?'){
                quote=quote.substring(0,quote.length()-1);
            }
            quote.trim();
            byte response=0;
            int j=0;
            //check the knowledgeBase for a match or change topic
            while(response==0){
                //if a match is found, reply with the answer
                if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),knowledgeBase[j*2])){
                    response=2;
                    int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*knowledgeBase[(j*2)+1].length);
                    addText("\nPollockoraptor:\t"+knowledgeBase[(j*2)+1][r]);
                }
                j++;
                //if a match is not found, go to change topic
                if(j*2==knowledgeBase.length-1 && response==0){
                    response=1;
                }
            }
            //change topic if bot is lost
            if(response==1){
                int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*knowledgeBase[knowledgeBase.length-1].length);
                addText("\nPollockoraptor:\t"+knowledgeBase[knowledgeBase.length-1][r]);
            }
            addText("\n");
        }
    }
    //format the input
    public void addText(String str){
        dialog.append(str);
    }
    //check the knowledgeBase for a match
    public boolean inArray(String in,String[] str){
        boolean match=false;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            if(str[i].equals(in)){
                match=true;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be blunt, but your problem is simply one of sloppy code.

You're adding the dialog **twice**  to the window container, once in the JScrollPane and once by itself.

```
public ChatBot() {
  super("Pollockoraptor");
  setSize(600, 400);
  setResizable(true);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  dialog.setEditable(false);
  dialog.setLineWrap(true);
  dialog.setOpaque(false);
  scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
  input.addKeyListener(this);

  // **** adding a bunch of junk **without** constraings??
  window.add(scroll);  // *** add scrollpane *with* dialog here
  window.add(label);
  window.add(input);

  // .....

  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  // Dialog
  c.weightx = 1.0;
  c.weighty = 1.0;
  c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
  c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;
  c.gridwidth = 3;
  c.gridheight = 2;
  window.add(dialog, c); // *** then add dialog by itself*** ???? WTF???
```

Don't do that. Instead add it to the JScrollPane, add the JScrollPane to the container **with GridBagConstraints** and leave it at that.

You've got several other components that you're adding to window **without GridBagConstraints**, almost without thought, almost as if you're randomly and sloppily coding without planning(?). Don't do this either. Stop, plan what you want to code first, and only then create your code. Don't type it out free-thought as that's sloppy and will never work. Honest errors are fine, but sloppy coding, nope.

Comment: +1 for noticing all the "junk" that is being added without constraints. None of that code is needed.

Comment: @camickr: thanks, and I 1+ your answer immediately as well. This guy is just throwing random junk at the wall and seeing what sticks, and that's not how you can successfully create a program. I was blunt, perhaps too blunt, but the errors are just so egregious that I couldn't help myself.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying this right now... I am new to swing and all this stuff, so sorry for the obvious questions :)

Comment: Ok I will look up how ActionListener works and figure it out :)

Comment: I replaced KeyListener with actionListener now, did I do it right? Or am I missing something?...Edit2...

Answer (score 1):

> ) the scroll bar doesn't seem to work

```
window.add(dialog, c);
```

You need to add the scrollpane to the window, not the dialaog. Also when you create the dialog you should use something like:

```
JTextArea dialog = new JTextArea(5, 30);
```

so the text area can be created at a reasonable size.

> if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){

Don't use a KeyListener to listen for the Enter key. Instead add an ActionListener to the text field. The ActionListener will be invoked when the Enter key is pressed. Also why do you toggle the editable state of the text field? There is no need to do that.

> dialog.setText(dialog.getText()+str);

Don't do that to add text to the text area. Just use the `append(...)` method of the text area.